# Change <link href=""> by onclick .js

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick, href

I would like to change the style of site by clicking the icon

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styled.css" id="styles">
</head>
```

It's hard for me to get into href. At the moment I wrote this script:

```
<script>
    function changeTheme(){
    document.querySelector("link[href='styled.css']").href = "style.css";
    }            
</script>
```

but it only works one way and I want something like that:
(first click) styled.css -> style.css
(second click) style.css -> styled.css.
I feel that I started this function badly, so I am asking for help. What should a valid script look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if-else:

```js
function changeTheme() {
  const link = document.getElementById('styles');
  if (link.href.includes('d')) {
    link.href = 'style.css';
  } else {
    link.href = 'styled.css';
  }
}
```